# Django Template - How to check if dynamically constructed key has value in Object

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I've an object that contains names like

```
draft = {
  "name_ar": "test arabic",
  "name_en": "test english",
  "name_tr": "test turkish",
  "name_nl": "",
}
```

and I've `language_code` variable which will have either 'ar' or 'en' values. So before checking if key has value in the object what I did is I constructed the key first like below

```
{% with name='name_'|add:language_code %}
```

So now my query is I want to add class `grey-color` to div container if name doesn't have value in `draft` object. How can I achieve this?

```
{% with name='name_'|add:language_code %}
   <span class="secondary-title {% if not "how can I check here" %}grey-color{% endif %}">
{% endif %}
```

I'm very new to Django so happy to hear any suggestions or solution.

Comment: `{% if name not in draft %}`?

Comment: You can create a templatetag that gets you the value, passing the dictionary and the language. Should be a cleaner solution

Comment: Use [not in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#in-operator) operator!

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for your quick response. Your solution will check whether key exist or not right? but I want to check if that key has value or not in the object

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using template tags

```
@register.filter('get_value_from_dict')
def get_value_from_dict(dict_data, key):
    """
    usage example {{ your_dict|get_value_from_dict:your_key }}
    """
    if key:
        return dict_data.get(key)
```

and then in template

```
<span class="secondary-title {% if not draft|get_value_from_dict:name %}grey-color{% endif %}">
```